# SpringBoot crashes after deployment of war, on launching in heroku

Tags: spring-boot, ionic-framework, heroku, deployment, war

I'm trying to deploy my springboot application in heroku. This application contains a spriboot back end and ionic framework for front end. All these are packaged in a war file, which is being deployed successfully in my local tomcat and also it works like a charm. When I try to deploy this on heroku, on deploying the Springboot it crashes with the following error:

> 2019-06-02T10:14:27.864513+00:00 app[web.1]: :: Spring Boot ::
>   (v2.1.5.RELEASE) 2019-06-02T10:14:27.864559+00:00 app[web.1]:
>   2019-06-02T10:14:28.086513+00:00 app[web.1]: 2019-06-02 10:14:28.081 
>   INFO 4 --- [ost-startStop-1] c.m.g.movierama.MovieramaApplication
>   : Starting MovieramaApplication v0.0.1-SNAPSHOT on
>   5afc3cd9-f86f-466f-9b86-9f66bc5beae7 with PID 4
>   (/app/target/tomcat.12290/webapps/expanded/WEB-INF/classes started by
>   u40978 in /app) 2019-06-02T10:14:28.088166+00:00 app[web.1]:
>   2019-06-02 10:14:28.087  INFO 4 --- [ost-startStop-1]
>   c.m.g.movierama.MovieramaApplication     : No active profile set,
>   falling back to default profiles: default
>   2019-06-02T10:14:29.523921+00:00 app[web.1]: 2019-06-02 10:14:29.521 
>   INFO 4 --- [ost-startStop-1] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate
>   : Bootstrapping Spring Data repositories in DEFAULT mode.
>   2019-06-02T10:14:29.562415+00:00 app[web.1]: 2019-06-02 10:14:29.562 
>   INFO 4 --- [ost-startStop-1] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate
>   : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 26ms. Found 0 repository
>   interfaces. 2019-06-02T10:14:30.060948+00:00 app[web.1]: 2019-06-02
>   10:14:30.060  INFO 4 --- [ost-startStop-1]
>   faultConfiguringBeanFactoryPostProcessor : No bean named
>   'errorChannel' has been explicitly defined. Therefore, a default
>   PublishSubscribeChannel will be created.
>   2019-06-02T10:14:30.068963+00:00 app[web.1]: 2019-06-02 10:14:30.068 
>   INFO 4 --- [ost-startStop-1] faultConfiguringBeanFactoryPostProcessor
>   : No bean named 'taskScheduler' has been explicitly defined.
>   Therefore, a default ThreadPoolTaskScheduler will be created.
>   2019-06-02T10:14:30.075260+00:00 app[web.1]: 2019-06-02 10:14:30.075 
>   INFO 4 --- [ost-startStop-1] faultConfiguringBeanFactoryPostProcessor
>   : No bean named 'integrationHeaderChannelRegistry' has been explicitly
>   defined. Therefore, a default DefaultHeaderChannelRegistry will be
>   created. 2019-06-02T10:14:30.287747+00:00 app[web.1]: 2019-06-02
>   10:14:30.287  INFO 4 --- [ost-startStop-1]
>   trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean
>   'org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration'
>   of type
>   [org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$c5e20e2a]
>   is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for
>   example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
>   2019-06-02T10:14:30.363779+00:00 app[web.1]: 2019-06-02 10:14:30.363 
>   INFO 4 --- [ost-startStop-1] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker
>   : Bean
>   'org.springframework.integration.config.IntegrationManagementConfiguration'
>   of type
>   [org.springframework.integration.config.IntegrationManagementConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$30d3c959]
>   is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for
>   example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
>   2019-06-02T10:14:30.399455+00:00 app[web.1]: 2019-06-02 10:14:30.399 
>   INFO 4 --- [ost-startStop-1] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker
>   : Bean 'integrationDisposableAutoCreatedBeans' of type
>   [org.springframework.integration.config.annotation.Disposables] is not
>   eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example:
>   not eligible for auto-proxying) 2019-06-02T10:14:30.471157+00:00
>   app[web.1]: 2019-06-02 10:14:30.470  INFO 4 --- [ost-startStop-1]
>   o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring
>   embedded WebApplicationContext 2019-06-02T10:14:30.471413+00:00
>   app[web.1]: 2019-06-02 10:14:30.471  INFO 4 --- [ost-startStop-1]
>   o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext:
>   initialization completed in 2334 ms 2019-06-02T10:14:31.100545+00:00
>   app[web.1]: 2019-06-02 10:14:31.100  INFO 4 --- [ost-startStop-1]
>   com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
>   2019-06-02T10:14:31.767558+00:00 app[web.1]: 2019-06-02 10:14:31.767 
>   INFO 4 --- [ost-startStop-1] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource
>   : HikariPool-1 - Start completed. 2019-06-02T10:14:31.942093+00:00
>   app[web.1]: 2019-06-02 10:14:31.940  INFO 4 --- [ost-startStop-1]
>   o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing
>   PersistenceUnitInfo [ 2019-06-02T10:14:31.942096+00:00 app[web.1]:
>   name: default 2019-06-02T10:14:31.942098+00:00 app[web.1]: ...]
>   2019-06-02T10:14:32.216822+00:00 app[web.1]: 2019-06-02 10:14:32.216 
>   INFO 4 --- [ost-startStop-1] org.hibernate.Version
>   : HHH000412: Hibernate Core {5.3.10.Final}
>   2019-06-02T10:14:32.223817+00:00 app[web.1]: 2019-06-02 10:14:32.223 
>   INFO 4 --- [ost-startStop-1] org.hibernate.cfg.Environment
>   : HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
>   2019-06-02T10:14:32.694566+00:00 app[web.1]: 2019-06-02 10:14:32.694 
>   INFO 4 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.hibernate.annotations.common.Version
>   : HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.0.1.Final}
>   2019-06-02T10:14:33.118437+00:00 app[web.1]: 2019-06-02 10:14:33.118 
>   INFO 4 --- [ost-startStop-1] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect
>   : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
>   2019-06-02T10:14:34.600268+00:00 app[web.1]: 2019-06-02 10:14:34.599 
>   INFO 4 --- [ost-startStop-1] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean
>   : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
>   2019-06-02T10:14:35.687724+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up
>   to crashed 2019-06-02T10:14:35.405611+00:00 app[web.1]: 2019-06-02
>   10:14:35.405  WARN 4 --- [ost-startStop-1]
>   ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered
>   during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt:
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'requestMappingHandlerAdapter' defined in
>   class path resource
>   [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/servlet/WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration.class]:
>   Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to
>   instantiate
>   [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter]:
>   Factory method 'requestMappingHandlerAdapter' threw exception; nested
>   exception is java.lang.BootstrapMethodError:
>   java.lang.IllegalAccessError: no such method:
>   io.reactivex.Flowable.fromPublisher(Publisher)Flowable/invokeStatic
>   2019-06-02T10:14:35.409906+00:00 app[web.1]: 2019-06-02 10:14:35.408 
>   INFO 4 --- [ost-startStop-1] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean
>   : Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
>   2019-06-02T10:14:35.415771+00:00 app[web.1]: 2019-06-02 10:14:35.415 
>   INFO 4 --- [ost-startStop-1] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource
>   : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown initiated...
>   2019-06-02T10:14:35.449333+00:00 app[web.1]: 2019-06-02 10:14:35.449 
>   INFO 4 --- [ost-startStop-1] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource
>   : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown completed. 2019-06-02T10:14:35.460889+00:00
>   app[web.1]: 2019-06-02 10:14:35.460  INFO 4 --- [ost-startStop-1]
>   ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener :
>   2019-06-02T10:14:35.460892+00:00 app[web.1]:
>   2019-06-02T10:14:35.460894+00:00 app[web.1]: Error starting
>   ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your
>   application with 'debug' enabled. 2019-06-02T10:14:35.470103+00:00
>   app[web.1]: 2019-06-02 10:14:35.469 ERROR 4 --- [ost-startStop-1]
>   o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed
>   2019-06-02T10:14:35.470106+00:00 app[web.1]:
>   2019-06-02T10:14:35.470111+00:00 app[web.1]:
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'requestMappingHandlerAdapter' defined in
>   class path resource
>   [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/servlet/WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration.class]:
>   Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to
>   instantiate
>   [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter]:
>   Factory method 'requestMappingHandlerAdapter' threw exception; nested
>   exception is java.lang.BootstrapMethodError:
>   java.lang.IllegalAccessError: no such method:
>   io.reactivex.Flowable.fromPublisher(Publisher)Flowable/invokeStatic
>   2019-06-02T10:14:35.470113+00:00 app[web.1]: at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:627)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
>   2019-06-02T10:14:35.470114+00:00 app[web.1]: at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:607)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
>   2019-06-02T10:14:35.470117+00:00 app[web.1]: at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1321)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
>   2019-06-02T10:14:35.470118+00:00 app[web.1]: at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1160)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
>   2019-06-02T10:14:35.470124+00:00 app[web.1]: at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:555)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
>   2019-06-02T10:14:35.470125+00:00 app[web.1]: at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:515)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
>   2019-06-02T10:14:35.470127+00:00 app[web.1]: at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
>   2019-06-02T10:14:35.470128+00:00 app[web.1]: at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
>   2019-06-02T10:14:35.470129+00:00 app[web.1]: at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
>   2019-06-02T10:14:35.470131+00:00 app[web.1]: at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
>   2019-06-02T10:14:35.470132+00:00 app[web.1]: at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:843)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
>   2019-06-02T10:14:35.470133+00:00 app[web.1]: at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:877)
>   ~[spring-context-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
>   2019-06-02T10:14:35.470135+00:00 app[web.1]: at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:549)
>   ~[spring-context-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
>   2019-06-02T10:14:35.470136+00:00 app[web.1]: at
>   org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:142)
>   ~[spring-boot-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
>   2019-06-02T10:14:35.470138+00:00 app[web.1]: at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:775)
>   ~[spring-boot-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
>   2019-06-02T10:14:35.470139+00:00 app[web.1]: at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397)
>   ~[spring-boot-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
>   2019-06-02T10:14:35.470141+00:00 app[web.1]: at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:316)
>   ~[spring-boot-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
>   2019-06-02T10:14:35.470142+00:00 app[web.1]: at
>   org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.run(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:157)
>   [spring-boot-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
>   2019-06-02T10:14:35.470143+00:00 app[web.1]: at
>   org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.createRootApplicationContext(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:137)
>   [spring-boot-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
>   2019-06-02T10:14:35.470150+00:00 app[web.1]: at
>   org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.onStartup(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:91)
>   [spring-boot-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
>   2019-06-02T10:14:35.470151+00:00 app[web.1]: at
>   org.springframework.web.SpringServletContainerInitializer.onStartup(SpringServletContainerInitializer.java:171)
>   [spring-web-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
>   2019-06-02T10:14:35.470153+00:00 app[web.1]: at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5272)
>   [webapp-runner.jar:na] 2019-06-02T10:14:35.470155+00:00 app[web.1]: at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
>   [webapp-runner.jar:na] 2019-06-02T10:14:35.470156+00:00 app[web.1]: at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1423)
>   [webapp-runner.jar:na] 2019-06-02T10:14:35.470157+00:00 app[web.1]: at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1413)
>   [webapp-runner.jar:na] 2019-06-02T10:14:35.470159+00:00 app[web.1]: at
>   java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
>   [na:1.8.0_212-heroku] 2019-06-02T10:14:35.470160+00:00 app[web.1]: at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
>   [na:1.8.0_212-heroku] 2019-06-02T10:14:35.470161+00:00 app[web.1]: at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
>   [na:1.8.0_212-heroku] 2019-06-02T10:14:35.470163+00:00 app[web.1]: at
>   java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_212-heroku]
>   2019-06-02T10:14:35.470167+00:00 app[web.1]: Caused by:
>   org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to
>   instantiate
>   [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter]:
>   Factory method 'requestMappingHandlerAdapter' threw exception; nested
>   exception is java.lang.BootstrapMethodError:
>   java.lang.IllegalAccessError: no such method:
>   io.reactivex.Flowable.fromPublisher(Publisher)Flowable/invokeStatic
>   2019-06-02T10:14:35.470169+00:00 app[web.1]: at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:185)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
>   2019-06-02T10:14:35.470171+00:00 app[web.1]: at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:622)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
>   2019-06-02T10:14:35.470173+00:00 app[web.1]: ... 28 common frames
>   omitted 2019-06-02T10:14:35.470174+00:00 app[web.1]: Caused by:
>   java.lang.BootstrapMethodError: java.lang.IllegalAccessError: no such
>   method:
>   io.reactivex.Flowable.fromPublisher(Publisher)Flowable/invokeStatic
>   2019-06-02T10:14:35.470176+00:00 app[web.1]: at
>   org.springframework.core.ReactiveAdapterRegistry$RxJava2Registrar.registerAdapters(ReactiveAdapterRegistry.java:248)
>   ~[spring-core-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
>   2019-06-02T10:14:35.470177+00:00 app[web.1]: at
>   org.springframework.core.ReactiveAdapterRegistry.(ReactiveAdapterRegistry.java:83)
>   ~[spring-core-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
>   2019-06-02T10:14:35.470178+00:00 app[web.1]: at
>   org.springframework.core.ReactiveAdapterRegistry.getSharedInstance(ReactiveAdapterRegistry.java:179)
>   ~[spring-core-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
>   2019-06-02T10:14:35.470180+00:00 app[web.1]: at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:168)
>   ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
>   2019-06-02T10:14:35.470181+00:00 app[web.1]: at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurationSupport.createRequestMappingHandlerAdapter(WebMvcConfigurationSupport.java:593)
>   ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
>   2019-06-02T10:14:35.470185+00:00 app[web.1]: at
>   org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration.createRequestMappingHandlerAdapter(WebMvcAutoConfiguration.java:496)
>   ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
>   2019-06-02T10:14:35.470186+00:00 app[web.1]: at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurationSupport.requestMappingHandlerAdapter(WebMvcConfigurationSupport.java:561)
>   ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
>   2019-06-02T10:14:35.470188+00:00 app[web.1]: at
>   org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration.requestMappingHandlerAdapter(WebMvcAutoConfiguration.java:484)
>   ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
>   2019-06-02T10:14:35.470205+00:00 app[web.1]: at
>   org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$30cf5eaa.CGLIB$requestMappingHandlerAdapter$7()
>   ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
>   2019-06-02T10:14:35.470206+00:00 app[web.1]: at
>   org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$30cf5eaa$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$5e7c894e.invoke()
>   ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
>   2019-06-02T10:14:35.470213+00:00 app[web.1]: at
>   org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:244)
>   ~[spring-core-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
>   2019-06-02T10:14:35.470214+00:00 app[web.1]: at
>   org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:363)
>   ~[spring-context-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
>   2019-06-02T10:14:35.470216+00:00 app[web.1]: at
>   org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$30cf5eaa.requestMappingHandlerAdapter()
>   ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
>   2019-06-02T10:14:35.470217+00:00 app[web.1]: at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_212-heroku] 2019-06-02T10:14:35.470219+00:00 app[web.1]: at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_212-heroku] 2019-06-02T10:14:35.470220+00:00 app[web.1]: at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_212-heroku] 2019-06-02T10:14:35.470222+00:00 app[web.1]: at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_212-heroku] 2019-06-02T10:14:35.470223+00:00 app[web.1]: at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
>   2019-06-02T10:14:35.470224+00:00 app[web.1]: ... 29 common frames
>   omitted 2019-06-02T10:14:35.470226+00:00 app[web.1]: Caused by:
>   java.lang.IllegalAccessError: no such method:
>   io.reactivex.Flowable.fromPublisher(Publisher)Flowable/invokeStatic
>   2019-06-02T10:14:35.470227+00:00 app[web.1]: at
>   java.lang.invoke.MethodHandleNatives.linkMethodHandleConstant(MethodHandleNatives.java:483)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_212-heroku] 2019-06-02T10:14:35.470228+00:00 app[web.1]:
>   ... 47 common frames omitted 2019-06-02T10:14:35.470231+00:00
>   app[web.1]: Caused by: java.lang.LinkageError: loader constraint
>   violation: when resolving method
>   "io.reactivex.Flowable.fromPublisher(Lorg/reactivestreams/Publisher;)Lio/reactivex/Flowable;"
>   the class loader (instance of
>   org/apache/catalina/loader/ParallelWebappClassLoader) of the current
>   class,
>   org/springframework/core/ReactiveAdapterRegistry$RxJava2Registrar, and
>   the class loader (instance of sun/misc/Launcher$AppClassLoader) for
>   the method's defining class, io/reactivex/Flowable, have different
>   Class objects for the type org/reactivestreams/Publisher used in the
>   signature 2019-06-02T10:14:35.470232+00:00 app[web.1]: at
>   java.lang.invoke.MethodHandleNatives.resolve(Native Method)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_212-heroku] 2019-06-02T10:14:35.470234+00:00 app[web.1]: at
>   java.lang.invoke.MemberName$Factory.resolve(MemberName.java:975)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_212-heroku] 2019-06-02T10:14:35.470235+00:00 app[web.1]: at
>   java.lang.invoke.MemberName$Factory.resolveOrFail(MemberName.java:1000)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_212-heroku] 2019-06-02T10:14:35.470236+00:00 app[web.1]: at
>   java.lang.invoke.MethodHandles$Lookup.resolveOrFail(MethodHandles.java:1394)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_212-heroku] 2019-06-02T10:14:35.470238+00:00 app[web.1]: at
>   java.lang.invoke.MethodHandles$Lookup.linkMethodHandleConstant(MethodHandles.java:1750)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_212-heroku] 2019-06-02T10:14:35.470239+00:00 app[web.1]: at
>   java.lang.invoke.MethodHandleNatives.linkMethodHandleConstant(MethodHandleNatives.java:477)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_212-heroku] 2019-06-02T10:14:35.470240+00:00 app[web.1]:
>   ... 47 common frames omitted

Comment: Sorry for the format of the logs, as I'm newbie in logs upload , if someone can also tell how to make them more readable I'll be glad